# Finding location of class for BeautifulSoup

Tags: html, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm struggling with BeautifulSoup. I want to scrape the links of the contests in the table on the right side of [Transfermarkt][1]

How I locate it so far:

```
div1 = soup.find('div', {'class': 'large-4 columns'})
div2 = div1.find('div', {'class': 'box'})
table = div2.find('table')
table_body = table.find('tbody')
contest = table_body.find_all('a')
```

Problem is that this is not specific enough. I sometimes find double values, which completely destroy my structure...

Is there a better way to locate this exact position?

The position I need: "a" "title" inside of "td" "class=no-border-links"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is better to use `select` for this case.

```
for title in soup.select('.large-4.columns td.no-border-links > a'):
    if title.text:
        print(title.text)
```

Output will be

```
Weltmeisterschaft 2014
UEFA Champions League
1.Bundesliga
1.Bundesliga
1.Bundesliga
1.Bundesliga
FC Bayern München
1.Bundesliga
UEFA Champions League
1.Bundesliga
1.Bundesliga
1.Bundesliga
Deutschland
Deutschland
Weltmeisterschaft 2018
Weltmeisterschaft 2014
Weltmeisterschaft 2010
Europameisterschaft 2016
Europameisterschaft 2012
Weltmeisterschaft 2014
U21-Europameisterschaft 2009
UEFA Champions League
1.Bundesliga
Weltmeisterschaft 2010
Deutschland
UEFA Champions League
UEFA Champions League
UEFA Champions League
UEFA Champions League
UEFA Champions League
UEFA Champions League
UEFA Champions League
UEFA Champions League
UEFA Champions League
UEFA Super Cup
FC Bayern München
FC Bayern München
FC Bayern München
Deutschland
FIFA Klub-WM
DFB-Pokal
DFB-Pokal
DFB-Pokal
DFB-Pokal
DFL-Supercup
DFL-Supercup
DFL-Supercup
DFB-SuperCup
DFB-Pokal
U21-Europameisterschaft 2009
```

Comment: Thanks, but there are some missing values. "Deutschland" is missing and "FC Bayern München" as well... they are not titles. Deutschland is only in a href under the class 'no-border-links' and Bayern is in a class.... How can I implement these exceptions?

Comment: @viktor updated my answer. It loses its order but it gives what you want.

Comment: Hmm it's still not working. Now I get about 70 values... Even Schalke is in the list now, which is only on the table on the left side of the page...

Comment: Hmm. Updated again. I think i got it right this time.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following to get the desired content:

```
import re
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

URL = "https://www.transfermarkt.de/jumplist/erfolge/spieler/17259"

res = requests.get(URL,headers={"User-Agent":"Mozilla/5.0"})
soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text,"lxml")
for items in soup.select(".table-header:contains('Alle Titel') + table tr"):
    if not items.find("a",string=re.compile("\w")):continue
    item = items.find("a",string=re.compile("\w")).text
    print(item)
```

To get the link as well, try below:

```
import re
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib.parse import urljoin

URL = "https://www.transfermarkt.de/jumplist/erfolge/spieler/17259"

res = requests.get(URL,headers={"User-Agent":"Mozilla/5.0"})
soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text,"lxml")
for items in soup.select(".table-header:contains('Alle Titel') + table tr"):
    if not items.find("a",string=re.compile("\w")):continue
    item = items.find("a",string=re.compile("\w")).text
    try:
        link = urljoin(URL,items.select_one("a[href^='/']").get("href"))
    except AttributeError: link = ""
    print(item,link)
```

Comment: Thanks, this is working, but I also need the links. All in all in a structured order... I have updated my code at the top...

Some players like this one here: https://www.transfermarkt.de/jumplist/erfolge/spieler/143891

completely destroy my structure...

Comment: Check out the update. Make sure to create another post if you need additional help @viktor.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the `select` function in the soup library where you can use [CSS selectors](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp).

In your case, you could use something like-

```
a_tags = soup.select("td[class='no-border-links'] > a")
```

Now you can iterate over this to get the titles using the `text` attribute.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! Unfortunately this is not working.. I already have the titles. I need the links of the according club or contest...